# How to set div using Z-index and fix css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Area of concern -

- My Blue Div is overlapping over the green div. (I want to have a
  green Div then at the side Blue Div)
- On `Mouseover` loaded content is making the blue div to fall down
  however im trying to set "mydatatoshow" div to be over
  "rightsideblock" using jquery `z-index` property.

Kindly have a look at it and let me know the possible solution.

My Working code ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.container{width:999px;}
.leftsideblock{float:left; border:1px solid green;width:674px;}
.rightsideblock{border:5px solid blue;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
        $('.mydatatoshow').css('z-index', '9999');
        $('.mydatatoshow').show();
        var mydata = $(this).text();
        $('.mydatatoshow').html(mydata);        
    });

$('.mydivdata').mouseout(function(){
$('.mydatatoshow').hide();
});


});
</script>

<title>Test To Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="leftsideblock">
    <div class="mydivdata">
<table width="650" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="193" valign="top">Monday 07 July 2012</td>
<td width="424">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

    <div class="mydivdata">
<table width="650" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="193" valign="top">Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM</td>
<td width="424">
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
    </div>


    <div class="mydatatoshow">
    </div>

    <div class="rightsideblock">
    <p>
    This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right    sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.
    </p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.container{width:999px;}
.leftsideblock{float:left; border:1px solid green;width:674px;}
.rightsideblock{border:5px solid blue;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<title>Test To Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <table>
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>
        <div class="leftsideblock">
            <div class="mydivdata">
                <table width="650" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="193" valign="top">Monday 07 July 2012</td>
                        <td width="424">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="mydivdata">
                <table width="650" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="193" valign="top">Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM</td>
                    <td width="424">
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="rightsideblock" style="top: 0;position: absolute;width: 300px;float: right;">
            <p style="z-index:-1">
                This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right    sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.
            </p>

        <div class="mydatatoshow" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999; float: right; position: absolute; display: none; ">



                    &nbsp;
                    Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM

                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.




            </div></div>

        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
            $('.mydatatoshow').css('z-index', '9999');
            $('.mydatatoshow').show();
       //     document.getElementById('to_hide').style.display='none';
            var mydata = $(this).text();
            $('.mydatatoshow').html(mydata);        
        });

    $('.mydivdata').mouseout(function(){
    $('.mydatatoshow').hide();
    //document.getElementById('to_hide').style.display='block';
    });


    });
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: thanks ..i want green and blue div side by side ..currently blue div is over the green ..i want green block and then Blue Block

Comment: @swapnesh I edit the code that green div and blue div be next to each other

Comment: wow 30% more to go ...the only thing left is now currently "This is right sidebar data....." div data is going to be hidden on mouseover effect but i want that the mouse over data to come over this div data through z-index......plz help

Comment: Do you mean that on `mouseover` you want mydatatoshow div contents to be shown on top of the rightsideblock div. And rightsideblock div become hidden by z index not by hiding that? yes?

Comment: @swapnesh I just forgot to test that in IE. there is a small bug in that! so i edit the code once again!

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only works if you specify a type of position.

Comment: It depends what you want to happen… Normally position:relative is what you want. Read http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: how can i fix this code, please provide a solution as what i want i already mentioned under the area of concern Google is not fetching the simple solution as im BAD with the CSS

Comment: i already tried, google and pasted what i did but if im not getting to fix i think im at the right place